# How to define xTaskNotify ulValue in FreeRTOS for STM32?

Tags: stm32, freertos

I am learning Task Notifications (https://www.freertos.org/xTaskNotify.html) and I am writing my own app to test it on STM32.

```
{
    uint8_t sportMode;
    uint8_t filmMode;
    uint8_t speedLimit;
    uint8_t driveModeValue;
    uint8_t acceleration;
    uint8_t deceleration;
    uint8_t sleepMode;
} streamDisplayMsg_t;

static void displayControlNewMsg(void *msg)
{
    if(displayControlTaskHandle != NULL)
    {
        streamDisplayMsg_t* displayControlMsg = msg;

        xTaskNotify(    displayControlTaskHandle, 0 | displayControlMsg,    eSetValueWithOverwrite);
    }
}
```

Is 0 | displayControlMsg ok or I should recalculate the event and how? I don't understand what value to use here. Thank you